# How can I optimize reading a UTF-8 string from a file with a known offset and size?

Tags: rust

I want to read a UTF-8 string from a file with a known offset and size,
so I wrote:

```
fn test(file: &mut File, offset: u64, length: usize) -> Result<String, String> {
    try!(file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(offset)).map_err(|err| err.to_string()));
    let mut buffer = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(length);
    buffer.resize(length, 0_u8);
    try!(file.read_exact(& mut buffer).map_err(|err| err.to_string()));
    let utf8_s = try!(from_utf8(&buffer).map_err(|err| "invalid utf-8 data in data".to_string()));
    Result::Ok(String::from(utf8_s))
}
```

In my code I dislike two things:

1. I initialized `Vec` with 0, but this is useless, because on the
   next line I call `file.read_exact`. Can I allocate memory in heap without
   initializing it?
2. I created `Vec` on the heap and at the end I allocate memory again via `String`. I allocate the same amount of memory and copy from one location to another. Is it possible to implement this function with `length` memory requirements, not `2 * length`?

Answer (score 4):

1. Rust has no concept of "write-only" memory, so the only way to avoid initialising the `Vec` would be with `unsafe` code.  Unless you can *prove* this is an *actual* performance problem for your program, just leave it as-is.
2. You could just use [`String::from_utf8`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8) instead, which does the conversion in-place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `read_to_string()` function in combination with `take()` function to read the exact number of bytes:

```
fn test(file: &mut File, offset: u64, length: usize) -> Result<String, String> {
    try!(file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(offset)).map_err(|err| err.to_string()));
    let mut res = String::new();//or you can use ::with_capacity(length);
    try!(file.take(length as u64)
            .read_to_string(&mut res)
            .map_err(|err| err.to_string())
            .and_then(|x| if x!=length {Err("wrong num bytes".to_string())}else{Ok(x)})
    );
    Result::Ok(res)
}
```

Comment: I need exactly `length` bytes, not to end of file as `read_to_string` do.

Comment: That is why it is used the function `take()` http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.take

Comment: But `take` read `at most`, not exactly number of bytes, I need error if file not contains enough bytes.

Comment: You're right, I did not realize this. But you can check the number of bytes after reading

Comment: Fixed. It gives error if number of bytes is not equal to the `length`